# Creating buttons in expandablelistview

Tags: android, button, controls, expandablelistview

My Question is

I have a expandable list view. in the expandable list i have  two buttons in each child in the list. Now i can able to add buttons in the child list. But i dont know how to get parent position and child position. with this parent and child values i need to call another activity. I dont know how to use expandablelistadapter and onChildClick method. Can anybody explain with example. Because am new to android.

Answer (score 2):

You wont get source code implementation as this is not a "gimme-teh-codez" website. Please try to ask questions more specific or tell us whats the problem with your source-code. You can use pastebin.com to direct us to your source code.

I shall point to some links that will help you get started:

Check out : An [example](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html) showing how to use the [child position](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener.html) 
and [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html)

Expandable lists have groups which contain children

Comment: Thank you. but the link you given is not working. Because the MainActivity added in the TextView class. but TextView accepts only Context object.

Comment: when i gave an example i did not give you a solution, read the first para of my answer again till you get it. Please dont expect copy paste solutions from this website. There is a good chance that you will be banned from posting here if you continue asking for spoon-feeding solutions. The example is perfectly right, you supposed to understand the concept of ExpandableListAdapter, not copy paste code from the example. Try learning from a android text book if your android concepts are not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The solution won't differ from simple ListViews, so you can take a look at something like [this article](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/11/android-custom-list-item-with-nested.html). Basically, when you define your views in getView() (or in case of expandable lists in getChildView()), you define click listeners for the buttons with setOnClickListener(). You use the button's setTag() method to set necessary information like its position and then read it inside the listener with getTag().

Comment: it should be similar to this http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html